# Geonetwork Catalog cannot edit Record (Invalid)

Tags: geonetwork

It boils down to how can we fix an invalid page?

The record in question shows a red button in catalog and mouse over text is Record (Invalid).

I can click the record and see the page but edit shows a page that is empty except for the GUI toolbar at the top of the page (Categories, Validate, Save Metadata, etc).

Might be better to ask first if duplicate linkage entries seen in the xml of a record cause a Geonetwork record to become invalid and uneditable? If so, can they be fixed?

Comment: What version of geonetwork, can you edit records that's aren't invalid?

Comment: @nmtoken - yes I can even open other records tagged invalid.

Comment: invalid, means invalid against a schema (something that tests the structure of the file).  Having more than one metadata record refencing the same link (some other resource) would not be a cause of an invalid record.